# C++ going from one part of the program to another

Tags: c++, function

So here is my problem. I have a program that has 11 functions. I want to call one function from another but I want that function to be execute from somewhere in the middle? Any suggestions how can this be done? goto function is a very bad habit so I don't want to use it.

EDIT:
I initialize the variables first with load() and then i use them in the while loop. The thing i want here is that when i call the function containing the while loop to start from inside it and not initialize the variables. Sorry for my bad english.

```
void play()
{
load();
    while (!key[KEY_ESC])
    {

        two();

        clear_keybuf();
        acquire_screen();

        clear_to_color(screen,makecol(0,0,0));


        line( screen, 3, 0, 3, 600, makecol( 255, 255, 255));
        line( screen, 797, 0, 797, 600, makecol( 255, 255, 255));
...

}
}
```

Comment: Please give further details / show us the code. What do you mean by 'somewhere in the middle?'

Comment: @Ignacio: What do public/private specifiers have to do with it?

Comment: Nothing. I'm just tired.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to execute from somewhere in the middle of a function that you call. Functions *are* things that you can call, hence the starts of functions are the places that a call can start executing from. Change this:

```
void function1() {
    do_something;
    // <-- I want to start here
    do_something_else;
}
```

Into this:

```
void function2(); // declaration - or just put function2 first

void function1() {
    do_something;
    function2();
}

void function2() {
    do_something_else;
}
```

Then call function2() if you only want to do the second part of function1.

You could instead write a function like this:

```
void function1(bool do_the_first_bit) {
    if (do_the_first_bit) {
        do_something;
    }
    do_something_else;
 }
```

Edit:

In you example, where you want to start inside the loop, change this:

```
void function1() {
    load();
    while (blah) {
        do_stuff;
    }
}
```

into this:

```
void function2() {
    // this avoids the test first time, so as to "start in the loop"
    do {
        do_stuff;
    } while (blah);
}

void function1() {
    load();
    if (blah) {
        function2();
    }
}
```

Then when you want to just do the loop, not the load, call `function2()`.

The repetition of "blah" in both functions should be avoided if possible - it's not clear to me whether "start in the loop" is intended to mean, "even if the loop condition is false, run the loop once anyway", but I've interpreted it that way because it's harder.

Another alternative here is:

```
void play() {
    static bool loaded = false;
    if (!loaded) {
        load();
        loaded = true;
    }
    do_the_other_stuff;
}
```

This will load the first time it's called, and not load on subsequent calls. Of course it's not thread-safe, which might be a concern: for thread-safe initialization look for `pthread_once`, or [equivalent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363808%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Aside:

Some languages (but not C++) have a concept called a "co-routine", which approximately speaking is a function that can return from somewhere in the middle and "remember" where it returned from, so that next time it is called it resumes from the same place. This behaviour can be jury-rigged in C or C++: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html, but it is certainly not recommended to do this as an alternative to defining one function for each "thing" that you want to do. Co-routines are useful for "picking up where you left off", not for "only doing selected parts of the function".

Comment: yes thats exactly what I want to do "picking up where I left off".. I will read the artcile now. thanks!

Comment: +1 for the ability to give a clear answer to a unclear question. I have to admit I gave up parsing the question "somewhere in the middle"

Comment: @Martin: when I say "jury-rigged", that co-routine stuff really is quite hacky. The author says *of his own code* in PuTTY, "As far as I know, this is the worst piece of C hackery ever seen in serious production code". He did it because he's very experienced and confident using C, it would be a mistake to use it because you're *not* sufficiently experienced and confident in C to come up with a less hacky way to solve your problem! Hacky code has unforeseen consequences, that you'll have to deal with...

Comment: My solution was to declare another variable that tells the program whether to initialize the variables or not. Pretty simple, but the idea was crucial.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear, expecially the "to be executer somewhere in the middle" part. However if your situation is like this:

```
void func1()
{
    func2();
}

void func2()
{
    // Do something;
}
```

So that func2 is declared below func1 you can do like this:

```
void func2();

void func1()
{
    func2();
}

void func2()
{
    // Do something;
}
```